# How to position Google map slighty below previous div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I would like to have a div with content and below a Google map which slightly goes underneath previous div.
This works nice if I set `z-index: -1` on map but in that case all buttons (like zoom in/out icons) don't function anymore, and setting `z-index: 99999` on div doesn't do anything.
What can I do to solve this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOBbVB

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="article">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p
    </div>
</div>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 9999999; /* This doesn't make it go over map? */
}


#map-canvas {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  /* z-index: -1; This works but disables buttons */
}
```

Comment: `z-index` only works when you set a `position` style. You have to give the `.container` a `position: relative;` style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply add below lines in your `.container` class and it should be fine

```
position:relative;
margin-bottom:10px;
```